# Brother MFC-7360N has misaligned prints

Tags: printing, cups, lpr

I need to print from a Debian 7.0 (Wheezy) box to a Brother MFC-7360N.  The resulting printouts are all shifted 1cm to the right and 1cm up.  This is particularly annoying if I want to print labels.  This problem does not occur with a machine running Debian 6.0 (Squeeze).  I have already made sure the paper size setting is correct.
The only drivers available for this multifunction printer are from Brother.  Why does this happen with the later edition of Debian and not the earlier?  How can I fix this alignment problem.

Comment: You say the paper size settings are correct, but have you checked the *page margin* settings (both in your applications, and possibly at driver level as well, if you can set them there)? (Also, this quesion might fit better on superuser, I'm flagging it for moving.)

Comment: Found the solution.  http://selig.ws/hejdo/en/computers/linux/brother-printing.html

I found it necessary to not add /usr/share/cups/mime/local.convs but instead edit /usr/share/cups/mime/cupsfilters.convs.  Comment out the line reading

Comment: `application/vnd.cups-pdf       application/vnd.cups-postscript 22      pdftops`
and add nearby this:

`application/vnd.cups-pdf application/vnd.cups-postscript 11 cpdftocps-mas`